# iOS showNativePicker() messes with title area

Tags: ios, codenameone, title, picker

If I invoke `Display.getInstance().showNativePicker(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME,...)` on an iOS device, my title area get messed up. It's usually a blue gradient without margins, with a white icon to the left and a white text font. "native:MainBold" is selected in theme.res. When the picker appears, the title icon text get drawn on top of the existing title area, shifted down and left. The text is now black and not-bold. Sometimes the black text even appears in two places. When I dismiss the native picker dialog, the title area looks more normal, but the margins are now non-zero. The reason I'm not using a `Picker` is that I need to know if the users pressed OK or Cancel. I'm not sure if a `Picker` would have helped either, as I copied the code directly from Picker.java. Is this by design, and can something be done about it?

Comment: Sarabjit Singh, why did you add the swift tag? I'm not programming in Swift.

Comment: You can edit the question and remove the tag. Do you invoke the showNativePicker call on the EDT? Do you use invokeAndBlock() anywhere or have a dialog open while doing that.

Comment: I invoke it in a button click handler, so I suppose it's on the EDT. No dialogs or invokeAndBlock(). BTW I found a workaround, nulling the title text and the icon temporarily.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots so I have a better idea?